# What is the product of two multivariate normal random variables with different length?

Tags: probability

Suppose $X$ is a $p$-dimensional multivariate normal random variable with conditional distribution

$$f_X (x\mid Z=z) = \mathcal{N}(\mu + Az, I\sigma^2),$$

Further suppose that

$$Z\sim \mathcal{N}(0, I),$$

where $Z$ is a $q$-dimensional multivariate normal random variable. (So in fact, $A$ is a $p\times q$ matrix.)

What is the joint distribution of $X$ and $Z$? In other words, what is the pdf

$$f_{X_1,\cdots,X_p,Z_1,\cdots,Z_q}(x_1,\cdots,x_p,z_1,\cdots,z_q)?$$

We can assume all the independence that we want (i.e. all $x_i$'s and $z_j$'s are independent)

I spent quite some time googling but all the examples I came across seem to implicitly assume that $X$ and $Y$ have the same dimension. For example, in this [Matrix Cookbook](http://compbio.fmph.uniba.sk/vyuka/ml/old/2008/handouts/matrix-cookbook.pdf) page 41, it talks about "product of Gaussian density" but assumes that two input vectors need to have same dimensions.

Comment: Did you mean "What is the distribution of $Y$?" ? The distribution of $X$ is just what you said it is.

Comment: @MichaelHardy My wording was probably confusing. Edited.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Conditional_distributions From this wiki you know the result that the conditional distribution of a multivariate normal is still multivariate normal. Can you match the result with your parameters? If yes you can arrive the converse result.

Comment: @BGM I did the computation and matched the results. However, I don't see where I used the assumptions that everything are independent? Usually what conditions will allow us to say that two jointly normal r.v. $X$ and $Y$ are again jointly normal if we "stack them together"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
X \mid Z=z \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu + Az, \sigma^2 I)
$$
$$
(X- AZ) \mid (Z=z) \sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2 I)
$$
Since the conditional distribution of $X-AZ$ given $Z$ does not depend on $Z,$ we must conclude that (1) $X-AZ$ and $Z$ are independent, and (2) the marginal (or "unconditional") distribution of $X-AZ$ is that same distribution.

Thus we have
$$
X-AZ\sim\mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2 I)
$$
and
$$
(X-Az) \text{ and } Z \text{ are independent.}
$$
Thus
$$
\begin{bmatrix} X-AZ \\ Z \end{bmatrix} \sim \mathcal N \left( \begin{bmatrix} \mu \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} \sigma^2 I & 0 \\ 0 & I \end{bmatrix} \right).
$$
$$
\begin{bmatrix} X \\ Z \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} I & A \\ 0 & I \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} X-AZ \\ Z \end{bmatrix}
$$

Therefore $\begin{bmatrix} X \\ Z \end{bmatrix}$ is multivariate normal and
$$
\operatorname{E}\begin{bmatrix} X \\ Z \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} I & A \\ 0 & I \end{bmatrix} \operatorname{E} \begin{bmatrix} X-AZ \\ Z \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} I & A \\ 0 & I \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \mu \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \mu \\ 0 \end{bmatrix},
$$
and
$$
\operatorname{var} \begin{bmatrix} X \\ Z \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} I & A \\ 0 & I \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \sigma^2 I & 0 \\ 0 & I \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} I & 0 \\ A^T & I \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \sigma^2 I + A A^T & A \\ A^T & I \end{bmatrix}.  
$$

Comment: Aha! $X - Az$ and $Z$ are independent was the missing piece. Thanks.